# DataInputStream.read(b, off, len) < len во много раз

Tags: java, android, сокет, потоки-данных

Всем доброго времени суток. На компьютере запущен сервер. К нему присоединяется клиент (Android-приложение) и отправляет большой бинарный файл (вес файла 2934822 байт). Вот код отправки файла на сервер:

```
this.socket_out = this.socket.getOutputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream mByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
while (true) {
    byte[] i1 = new byte[65536];
    int i2 = mFileInputStream.read(i1, 0, 65536);
    Log.v("", "read=" + i2);
    if (i2 < 0) {
        mByteArrayOutputStream.close();
        mFileInputStream.close();
        break;
    } else {
        mByteArrayOutputStream.write(i1, 0, i2);
        mByteArrayOutputStream.flush();
    }
}
mFile.delete();
byte[] i1 = mByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
Log.v("", "sent=" + i1.length);
this.socket_out.write(i1);
this.socket_out.flush();
```

И логи приложения:

> read=65536
>
> read=65536
>
> ...
>
> read=65536
>
> read=51238
>
> sent=2934822

Вот код получения файла на сервере:

```
this.in = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());

while (
    byte[] i1 = new byte[65536];
    int i2 = this.in.read(i1, 0, 65536);
    if (i2 > -1) {
        System.out.print(i2);
        ...
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

И стандартный вывод:

> 12974
>   1440
>   1440
>   11520
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   7200
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   11520
>   1440
>   1440
>   59040
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   1440
>   17280
>   ...

Почему `DataInputStream` не читает сразу по 65536 (2^16) байтов, а читает по 1440, 7200, 12974.. ? Как заставить считывать в массив `b` по столько, сколько я указал в параметре `len` метода `DataInputStream.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`?

Comment: вообще у `DataInputStream` есть методы `readFully` которые вычитают сколько сказано или выбросят EOF если поток кончится раньше. Еще, вынесите создание буфера за цикл, его можно переиспользовать.

Answer (score 0):

Отрывок кода использования метода `DataInputStream.readFully`:

```
this.in = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
        final byte[] i1 = new byte[65536];
        while (

            int i2 =in.readFully(i1);
            if (i2 > -1) {
                System.out.print(i2);
                ///...
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```